# Invoke a method from another assembly

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-assembly

I have Tools.dll file that contains MyMethod() like this :

```
    public void MyMethod()
    {
        global::System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Sth");
    }
```

Now , I am trying to run this assembly method from another file :

```
        System.Reflection.Assembly myDllAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(@"PATH\Tools.dll");
 myDllAssembly.GetType().GetMethod("MyMethod").Invoke(myDllAssembly, null); //here we invoke MyMethod.
```

After running 'System.NullReferenceException' happens . It says "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

So How can I fix it ?!

Im sure this .dll building truth without problem .

Note : the assembly code come from : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32828/Using-Reflection-to-load-unreferenced-assemblies-a

Comment: Is the method you are calling is static or instance method?

Comment: @Adil It is Instance .

Comment: In the first parameter you have to pass instance of class on which you want to call the intended method but you are passing the assembly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember, that 'Invoke' requires a class instance for non-static methods, therefore you should use construction like this:

```
Type type = myDllAssembly.GetType("TypeName");
type.GetMethod("MyMethod").Invoke(Activator.CreateInstance(type), null);
```

#### Complete example with parameterised constructor and method

*Class code:*

```
public class MyClass
{
    private string parameter;

    /// <summary>
    /// конструктор
    /// </summary>
    public MyClass(string parameter)
    {
        this.parameter = parameter;
    }

    public void MyMethod(string value)
    {
        Console.Write("You parameter is '{0}' and value is '{1}'", parameter, value);
    }
}
```

*Invokation code:*

```
Type type = typeof(MyClass);
// OR
type = assembly.GetType("MyClass");
type.GetMethod("MyMethod").Invoke(Activator.CreateInstance(type, "well"), new object[] { "played" });
```

*Result:*

```
You parameter is 'well' and value is 'played'
```

Comment: Yeah ! It is true and work . But one more question : Your code work on a class which contains no constructor . But what if I want to pass some arguments on constructor of class (not method) ?!

Comment: In this case modify Activator method: Activator.CreateInstance(type, arg1, arg2, ..., argN), where args are constructor's parameters.

Answer (score 4):

This

```
myDllAssembly.GetType()
```

is wrong... it will return the `typeof(Assembly)`

you have to use the [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0cd10tb.aspx)

```
myDllAssembly.GetType("ClassOfMyMethod")
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to supply a name in your [`GetType(name)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0cd10tb(v=vs.110).aspx) call - at the moment, you're calling the standard [`GetType()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype(v=vs.110).aspx) that every object implements and so you're getting the [`Assembly`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) type - and that doesn't have a `MyMethod` method.